# Testing In-App-Purchase on iPhone with Test Account in Sandbox - Cannot Sign In

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am testing my first in-app-purchase but have trouble successfully signing in to AppStore. The Test account is created and validated (confirmed) by Apple. I signed out from iTunes account in Settings->Store.

When I hit Buy button within my app I am asked if I want to confirm buying this item. I hit Buy and it prompts to Sign In (with [Environment Sandbox]). I enter username/password - they are correct and it prompts "Verification Required" to make first purchases. So far so good but.. this is where things are getting stuck.

I get redirected to AppStore on iPhone and login is prompted again. I enter and it prompts, sort of, with empty alert saying "[Environment Sandbox]" message and the Cancel, Continue buttons. Then it loops forever: Login -> Prompt to continue -> Login -> Prompt to continue, etc.

How to avoid this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your Test Account Credentials. Because these credentials are in App store not in Sandbox.I also got same problem but when i changed these credentials to new

Comment: I added a new test user but did not validate it when Apple sent me an email. Just went to purchase and it did happen. Thanks